# Work item 0 is invalid and can't be saved

Tags: visual-studio, automation, automated-tests, microsoft-test-manager, tcm

I am trying to import automated test cases to Microsoft test manager (Using TCM.exe)
I have done this before but when I try this now it give me this error:

> work item 0 is invalid and can't be saved. Exception: 'F237124 work
>   item is not ready to save'.

I used the command:

```
tcm testcase /import /storage:"C:\Data\Banan\Projects\Bcc\TestProject\bin\Debug\TestProject.dll" /category:"XXXXX" /syncsuite:18888
```

where XXXXX is the test category, and the other field are specified in the configuration file of the TCM.

Comment: I build my project again and rebuild it and rebuild the entire solution and now only three test cases are imported but not the others

Answer (score 0):

In import I suppose you are importing (providing values) to some or all attributes from your code file. The error suggests that you are importing some mandatory attribute (I think workitemId may some thing else) to template & its value is not given or default zero value is provided for that attribute, which gives error while saving.

For the three test cases that are imported, please check that you have provided attributes values different from others (that are failed to import). I think that will route you to root of error. Please let me know if it works.

Comment: Thanks Pranav, the problem is fixed and it appears to be from the length of the test method, it was just too long.